# Evicting keys inside hashmap in redis

Tags: data-structures, redis

I have a giant hashmap in Redis which keeps on growing. Around 50k per day, upon the subsequent days this number will become less as the same keys would repeat. I want to limit this hashmap to 1 million key value pairs. I want to do this based on LRU.

I know I can do this with Redis' sorted set with timestamp as a value and removing entries which are not in range, but I need to retain the key value pair structure, when I move to sorted set I will be missing the key value structure as the value would be timestamp and I need to perform some string operations in the key to achieve the equivalent hash functionality (not feasible).

So my requirements are:

1. Key value pair structure
2. get values based on the given key or
   multiple keys
3. trimming the structure with 1 million pairs with
   the lru policy.

Can I achieve it with hash? I am also open for other suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use both `HASH` and `Sorted Set`.

> Save data in `HASH`

`HSET KEY FIELD VALUE`

With your data saved in `HASH`, you can achieve both *"Key value pair structure"* and *"get values based on the given key or multiple keys"*.

> Implement LRU with `Sorted Set`

`ZADD KEY TIMESTAMP FIELD`

With `Sorted Set`, you can save the timestamp as the score of a field. Each time when you access a field in `HASH`, update the score of the field with current timestamp.

If the number of members in `Sorted Set` is larger than a million, get fields whose score is too small (with `zcard` and `zrange`). Then remove these fields in both `HASH` and `Sorted Set`.

Comment: Good one. But doing two operations for all the actions seems a overhead to me. Will look out for better solutions (if any)

Comment: For what it's worth, that's the solution I would choose - I do but think there's a better one.